# Getting number values out of prodduct name in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem. We have coded item names which has certain values that I need to do calculations with.
I.E. ASG-120U9624M I need to extract only 120, 96, 24, as they are parameters required for calculations. Also 96 could be 220(2-3 digits). 24 could be only 12 or 24. I know that you can get values after certain symbols i.e (-, u) but can you detect that value ends before 12/24. If 96 value could be only 2 digits it would be easy but now it's out of my knowledge to do so. Need some help.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "-(\d+)U")))
```

C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "U(\d+)..M")))
```

D1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ".+(\d{2})M")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(IFERROR(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ".*U(\d{4})M")), 5) = 4, REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^ASG-(\d{3})U(\d{2})(\d{2})M$"), REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^ASG-(\d{3})U(\d{3})(\d{2})M$"))))
```

`LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ".*U(\d{4})M")), 5) = 4` - Determine the number of digits from U-M

`REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^ASG-(\d{3})U(\d{2})(\d{2})M$")` - use this regex if number of digits is 4.

`REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^ASG-(\d{3})U(\d{3})(\d{2})M$")` - use this regex if number of digits is 5.

Sample Sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your raw data runs A2:A. Place the following in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\d+)\D(\d+)(12|24)")))`

This one formula will extract all three columns of numbers.

The regex captures three groups, each contained in parentheses. It reads: "Any number of digits followed by one non-digit followed by any number of digits up to a 12 or 24."